# How set default date in annotation @CreatedDate?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, timezone

When creating a record, it needs to insert its date back with the offset of the time zone. How do I change the default time in this annotation? I use PostgreSQL if it matters.

My default time is UTC + 2, but I need only utc, without timezone.
E.g. When creating a new user, inserted date is 13.13.2017 14:00, but I need 13.13.2017 12:00.

I have a static method DateHelper.nowUTC () that returns the corresponding value. Is it possible that it will be called when the record is created?

Comment: What do you mean with "default time"? Either you can set a parameter in the annotation (which I'm not sure would be useful) or you just let Hibernate do its thing. Note that date values are independent of timezones, it's only when you need to format to or parse from a string that you'd need a timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JVM arguments it's resolve this problem: -Duser.timezone=UTC, but this set default tiimezone to UTC for aplication.

These settings can also be changed directly in the code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("user.timezone", "UTC");
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }

}
```